# How to find the approximate error in Stirlings Formula

Tags: approximation, standard-error

If we have the stirlings formula: $$N!=\sqrt{2\pi N}(\frac {N}{e})^N$$

And I am asked to find how big the N must be so our error is less then 1 %.

Because the error is in percentage, I am considering the relative error, which is the ration between the absolute and the actual value :

$$\frac{|N!-\sqrt{2\pi N}(\frac {N}{e})^N  |}{|N!|}=0.01$$

But I don't know how to proceed in finding the N value for this case of an error (which should be around 9, which is the answer to this)

Comment: See the first *inequality* [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation). (BTW what do you have *at hand*?)

Comment: the logarithm ? How is that connected to the error calculation. Is my initial formula regarding the calculation of the error correct?

Comment: 1) *the logarithm* - what? I mean the (double-sided) inequality stated first in that wiki page. 2) *How is that connected* - almost immediately (with some *elementary* math behind the scenes). 3) *Is my initial formula regarding the calculation of the error correct* - I don't see a formula for **the error**.

Comment: Roughly, the inequality says that the relative error is about $1/(12N)$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_error Is what I used initially

Comment: That's the Creation of the World. I mean, specifically, the error of Stirling's approximation. The wiki page contains some of these (particularly the inequality I've mentioned). What are you *allowed* to use? (The basic Stirling's approximation *itself* is *insufficient* here!)

Comment: I am allowed to use only this. I have the stirling formula and then I am asked about what should the value of N be, in order to have an error less then 1%, 0.01

Comment: Well, then try $N=1,2,\dots,8$, see that you're OK with $N=9$, and make one *believe* that the same will hold for $N>9$.

Comment: yes but that's not very efficient. It happens that it is valid for N>9, but if I had a case where it's found that  N>1000 , then it's no good

Comment: That's exactly what I'm talking about - *you must have a **proven** upper bound of the error **at hand***.

Comment: @moderators: feel free to remove *all* these comments.

Answer (score 1):

Well, using the formal definition we must solve:

$$1\space\text{%}\le100\space\text{%}\cdot\left|\frac{\text{n}!-\sqrt{2\pi\text{n}}\cdot\left(\frac{\text{n}}{e}\right)^\text{n}}{\text{n}!}\right|\tag1$$

And we find that:

$$\text{n}\ge9\tag2$$